# Display strokes on an InkCanvas, but do not capture events

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I am developing a touch screen application and allow users to add touch-based markup to an overlay over content using an ink canvas. I have reached a point where the view behind the overlay has an element that needs the user should be allowed to interact with, but events are captured by the InkCanvas and not by the underlying control. Is there a way to display strokes, but still allow controls behind the InkCanvas to capture events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `InkCanvas.IsHitTestVisible = false` and it will still display but you will not be able to interact with it and all events will go to elements lower in the z-order, which sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: For the record, it's IsHitTestVisible. Works like a charm, just the same. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed.  That's what I get for typing instead of copy-and-paste from my test program!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm toggling the InkCanvas. To accomplish this, I also had to set `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.None` to disable it.